# using CFileDialog::AddCheckButton fails

Tags: windows, mfc, common-dialog

OK, I am trying to use `CFileDialog::AddCheckButton`. The function call succeeds and I'm able to see the new check box.  I'm unable to see any events and while I can override `OnInitDialog`, overriding `OnOK` is ignored.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

//header

```cpp
class CTPSaveDialog : public CFileDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTPSaveDialog)
    static const CString CTPSaveDialog::m_cstrFilter;
public:
    BOOL m_bForce;
    CTPSaveDialog(
        LPCTSTR lpszDefExt = NULL,
        LPCTSTR lpszFileName = NULL,
        DWORD dwFlags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,
        CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL,
        DWORD dwSize = 0);
    ~CTPSaveDialog();
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedCheckForce();
    virtual void OnOK();
};
```

// implementation

```cpp
const CString CTPSaveDialog::m_cstrFilter = "JPEG images (*.jpg)|*.jpg|TIFF Format (*.tif)|*.tif|Windows Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|Portable Network Graphics (*.png)|*.png|GIF (*.gif)|*.gif||";

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CTPSaveDialog, CFileDialog)

CTPSaveDialog::CTPSaveDialog(LPCTSTR lpszDefExt, LPCTSTR lpszFileName, DWORD dwFlags, CWnd * pParentWnd, DWORD dwSize) :
    CFileDialog(FALSE, lpszDefExt, lpszFileName, dwFlags, m_cstrFilter, pParentWnd, dwSize, TRUE)
{
    AddCheckButton(IDC_CHK_FORCE, "Force", FALSE);
    m_bForce = FALSE;
    m_ofn.lpstrTitle = "Write Simulation To File";
}

CTPSaveDialog::~CTPSaveDialog()
{
}


BOOL CTPSaveDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CFileDialog::OnInitDialog();

    if (GetDlgItem(IDC_CHK_FORCE))
        SendDlgItemMessage(IDC_CHK_FORCE, BM_SETCHECK, m_bForce ? BST_CHECKED : BST_UNCHECKED);
    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTPSaveDialog, CFileDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHK_FORCE, &CTPSaveDialog::OnBnClickedCheckForce)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CTPSaveDialog::CTPSaveDialog()
{
    m_bForce = !m_bForce;
}

void CTPSaveDialog::OnOK()
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    CFileDialog::OnOK();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CFileDialog` with Vista style, windows messages are not handled in message map. Instead `CFileDialog` uses specific virtual functions. You only need to declare and define these functions.

Use `OnCheckButtonToggled` to detect if check box is clicked.

Use `OnFileNameOK` to detect when file is selected and `Open/Save` button is clicked.

Use `SetCheckButtonState` to set/unset the check button (not `SendDlgItemMessage`)

See [`CFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=vs-2017) for all available methods.

As stated in documentation, `OnInitDialog` is not supported either:

> Some `CFileDialog` methods are not supported under Windows Vista or
>   later. Check the individual method topic for information about whether
>   the method is supported. In addition, the following inherited
>   functions are not supported under Windows Vista or later:
>
> ```
> CDialog::OnInitDialog
> ...
> ```

Just do the initialization in the constructor or before calling `DoModal()`, and override these functions:

```cpp
class CTPSaveDialog : public CFileDialog
{
    ...
    virtual void OnCheckButtonToggled(DWORD dwIDCtl, BOOL bChecked);
    virtual BOOL OnFileNameOK();
};

void CTPSaveDialog::OnCheckButtonToggled(DWORD dwIDCtl, BOOL bChecked)
{
    if (dwIDCtl == IDC_CHK_FORCE)
        TRACE("Is checked? %d\n", bChecked);
}

BOOL CTPSaveDialog::OnFileNameOK()
{
    TRACE("Clicked Open/Save button\n");

    //return FALSE to close the dialog
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great, well-explained response :-)